# Generate all 10-digit phone numbers - backtracking

Tags: c

I need to generate all 10-digit telephone numbers which start with 0721 and have 3 distinct even digits (not counting the first 4). I know I should be using backtracking and I think I got the math behind this: out of the 6 remaining digits, we should have combinations of 5 taken as 3 (0, 2, 4, 6, 8) * combinations with repetitions of 5 taken as 3 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9). I'm just not sure how to write this in code as my `valid` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 6 // because we already know the first 4 digits

int v[N], even[5] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}, odd[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

void display()
{
    FILE *fout = fopen("telephone_numbers.txt", "w");
    if(!fout)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(fout, "0721 ");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fout, "%d", v[i]);
    }
    fputc(';', fout);
}

bool valid(int step, int v[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < step; i++)
    {
        if( // how do I implement the math here?
    }
}

bool solution(step)
{
    if(step == N)
        return true;
    return false;
}

void back(int step)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(valid(step))
        {
            if(solution(step))
            {
                display();
            }
            else back(step + 1);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    back(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `vaild` function cannot be useful until there are fewer than three digits left to explore in the search. Up until that point, any not-yet-valid candidate could become valid, since the next three digits added to it could be three distinct even digits.

Comment: The brute force way is to generate all 1000000 6-digit numbers and test each for validity.  Slightly better is to prune  once you hit initial digits that can't be valid.  Most interesting would be to generate the 10 * 6 * 20 * 125 correct numbers directly.

Comment: @stark: It is not clear the problem disallows duplicates in the even digits, just that there must be three that are distinct. It is also unclear that it requires there be only three that are distinct, rather than at least three that are distinct.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I find the statement quite ambiguous as well, but I think there should be exactly 3 distinct even digits